# How to use wget with headers in liveness probe in a yaml file in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

I am trying to use **wget** in my liveness probe in Kubernetes. Here is the code:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: test
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "99999999"
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - wget
        - -O- 
        - --header=
        - "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: abcde"
        - --header= 
        - "DD-API-KEY: a123456"
        - https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/1234567 | grep \"overall_state\":\"OK\"
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
```

But I am facing the following error when I use **describe** command in the pod:

```
Liveness probe failed: wget: bad port ' abcde'
```

My goal is to check an alert in Datadog. If the alert is red the pod will restart.

The **wget** command works in the terminal. It looks like the YAML file is facing some problems using the headers.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: I do not understand. There are a lot of questions about yaml files in kubernetes. Where should I put this one? Serve Fault?

Comment: error suggests issue with wget command, try to shell into pod and run wget command, check if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
    - name: busybox
      image: busybox
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          while true
          do
            sleep 15s
          done
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              wget -O- \
              --header "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: abcde" \
              --header "DD-API-KEY: a123456" \
              http://10.0.1.1:8000/api/v1/monitor/1234567 \
              | grep '"overall_state":"OK"'
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 10
```

YAML syntax includes pipe (`|`) for [literal block scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info/) and so incorporating a shell pipe (`|`) is more complicated.

An easy out is to use the above syntax for both (!) `command`'s which uses literal block scalars for the shell content.

I don't have access to DataDog but this *should* work.